# VScode, C/C++ wont compile - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble getting a C/C++ program running for an assignment on an M1 mac. Tried everything (summary of what has been attempted below).

Hey everyone,

I have changed my mac from an intel Mac to an M1 Mac and I can't get the template to work.... I have seen quite a few threads on here with a similar issue, but as not helped. Can anyone assist me please?

Thank you!

FYI,

The file was sent to us as a .zip.
I have unzipped it and placed all the contents in one folder and dropped it in my VScode workspace.

I used `open  ~/.zshrc` (did this from just any terminal location yeah?) to input:(first image)

`export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib`

`source  ~/.zshrc`

changed the bits in each file from:

`#include "SDL.h" // and #include "SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h"`

to:

`#include "SDL2/SDL.h" // and #include "SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h"`

and using the following to compile...

`gcc wall.c formulas.c robot.c main.c -o main -lSDL2`

but I still get the following:

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Any ideas how to get this working?

Thank you!

Please see image in link below for screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/54iAW.png

Comment: [Edit] your question and include a [mcve] in the question as text, not as images.  Make sure to include the full error message.

Comment: It appears that your library is arm only whereas your shell is running in Rosetta/x86 mode. Main options: install the x64/multi-arch library or run the shell in native mode (`arch -arm64 zsh`).

Comment: You should start reading your linker errors from top. And also show the start of the error messages to us. You only mentioned the summary which is rather useless.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.